# Lookup typescript type guard

Tags: typescript

I'm refactoring an app from a previous developer and I have a React Component which is basically a function that takes an object as an argument with the type `Tag`, we call that `Props`.

```
enum Tag {
    STANDARD = 0x00,
    UV_RANGE = 0x01,
}

export enum DataType {
    DROPDOWN = 'DROPDOWN',
    NUMBER = 'NUMBER',
    DYNAMIC_NUMBER = 'DYNAMIC_NUMBER',
    TIME_RANGE = 'TIME_RANGE',
}


export interface CommonTagDataConfig {
    type: DataType.DROPDOWN | DataType.NUMBER | DataType.DYNAMIC_NUMBER;
    max: number;
    min: number
}

export interface TimeRangeDataConfig {
    type: DataType.TIME_RANGE;
    toBuffer(interval: number): Buffer;
}
export type TagDataConfig = CommonTagDataConfig | TimeRangeDataConfig;


// Note there are two types
export const TagConfigurations: Partial<Record<Tag, TagDataConfig>> = {
    // ... Some before
    [Tag.UV_RANGE]: {
        type: DataType.TIME_RANGE,
        toBuffer(interval: number) {
            // … Some code, not important
            return Buffer.from(interval);
        },
    },
    [Tag.STANDARD]: {
        type: DataType.NUMBER,
        max: 900,
        min: 200,
    },
    // ... Some after
}
```

Along with that, I've legacy code with the following (for a brief of example I'm shortening the possibilities of the following map, also I rather prefer making my types compatible with what has been done, avoiding a full refactor, which might be long and not sure my customer pay for).

In the legacy code, there was only `CommonTagDataConfig` as TagDataConfig, but I added a new one called `TimeRangeDataConfig`. The effect of that is that now every component that consumes this type needs a guard, which I have done :

```
export function isTagConfigType<T extends DataType>(
  element: TagDataConfig | undefined,
  expectedType: T,
): element is TagDataConfig & { type: T } {
  return element?.type === expectedType;
}

// Used like this
if(isTagConfigType(TagConfigurations[props.tag]!, DataType.TIME_RANGE)) {
    console.warn('Not supposed to be used with TimeRangeType');
    return null
  }
```

The issue is that it pops at runtime and sometimes due to React-Hook-Rules I cannot use it otherwise I break the hook rule of conditional rendering.

That's why I'm looking for a **Typing solution**.

I would like to create a generic type that can ensure that the tag passed has a matching key `TagConfigurations` map with a value of type `TimeRangeDataConfig` or I could just say `{type: DataType.RANGE}`

I'm looking for the following syntax and how to write those two custom types.

```
type Props< = {
  tag: TagForConfig<TimeRangeDataConfig>
  // OR
  tag: TagForType<DataType.TIME_RANGE>
}
```

I guess I would need to use `typeof TagConfigurations` at some point ?

Therefore I want this usage:

```
function MyNewComponent({type: Tag.STANDARD}) {} // ERROR
function MyNesComponent({type: Tag.UV_RANGE}) {} // WORKS
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwEIFcBm2Q3gG8AoeM%20ZAFykoEsx5sYB7AWwApYBzALnigB2ATwCUfLLnzEAvsWIgBmVvAAqULkVLkAyioCCAOQAiegEpH4AXngAGAB42bAGi1kAqgDUA%20qcMBxAFErWwcARhdZeTsAB2YYSngFJXgjGigVIWiEEnIU0wB5AAUjfIB1A2CAciMC4rKDSpdcgzcAWXQA0yqW9s7G1xSATQM9VoBJAGEvHo6u62rh0cnpttn%203JUx1oCffyD5ze3dg0D%20yKjY%20PhaAUp8bCgwBAm2VmYBNS5U6heBbFoNDl4JRMiA%20N90qCAHQ1IolcrwAA%20KTSGSyUJmnSRKOoaJAMMW4ymmNMAG4tKwoHY%20IpWAAjfDksisG40pQMmAyC5xBI3O4wB5PVS0VggUyCLggCG-f6ArQgrLg1HQw47XwnAJM4HMCR4GDsPn4ABuUAgbPp%20DEGBwevJshAMR5wNBqnU0vesuCL1Ybw%20brSMoB2JUIrFEqlAY9APJxAA9LH4AZmHdgQALfAIWAISgAd2YzqyyG5VzA7yorq4ga4mBgNFoZb4hVgdFNAB5TOA4sBW58nBX3X8AQA%20IfBIFkePwKHT%20DaNgIBnYOIgAYAbU%20UM8x0CAF0%20OPcgWwTjIejVduAk1D2RKDqbfgDbdjabzRyRJpr9fJ4AyAln88QzCgH2AjJtcrCXNQtwDJ%208BwJQNYCNakgwFCTBsI%20-ImhAIhate0hXmQ%20FrhuuiGCY5h7h%20n4KseEJ4hiqydARh6UtS8AAJyOMxuQsgIfAAExcQMRG5JO05Qn%20or8Ng-JcnIk7erEAgKAkHYCKAMA3FwxA0fAhQsNEaDWAe1C8BWuHwJOybpgQ3BFpEk6tIM8B6BMKhuHoAAy8ATPkrSFPkBgBAYKjwOwYyJOp8CYNE8A5rQlCprBCgaVWNZ1u8ABicSfMEnwDrKIjENgmACGAdDvPArRCIp7wqew0QGcgjZNe%20B6lgI5ZwOp%20BpbWFUCNlMC5dYnx9RlnWro1zCGVCpk7jGokJkY%20bIP%203UaVpcUJUliU0HJjnOaUhgqAEFi%20f5gXBaF4VxcwmAQMA8AQLQADW2b5rp02GRQ%20Ybb1UbVv19aDTl6jXGgS4wE8T23vADLCqK4oCJKBUAn2iWYGgtCIII8DvBAQiIOmYCvYwcQVvw2OUGgrBE9wRUlWVA1VUIBggDmtXKbcDVNS1M3IG1AwdV1KUA4OQMTUNI0VuNA3IFNTVzeoC1yEtKSretYuaSj22JWm%203SEAA)

Comment: In your configuration there is no relationship at all between `Tag` and `TagDataConfig`; the fact that both identifiers mention "range" isn't enough.  How do you plan to express that relationship?  Right now this isn't a [mre]; it's easy for me to tell you to write `declare function TUTU(args: Tag.UV_RANGE): void;` but presumably that wouldn't work for you.

Comment: I mean, *maybe* [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkOdlW) is what you're looking for, but I had to define `TagDataConfig` to actually be a key-value mapping.  Is that what you want? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I've update the post with better insight, could you give me intel ? Also your links was nice, I would be happy that you explain both :-)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WokdjW) work for your new version?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining. Also, do you mind if I [edit] the question to fix a few things? (i.e., struck-thru text can just be deleted, since interested parties can check revision history; your playground code should all be included as plain-text in the question; the word "yield" doesn't imply an error condition and should therefore be changed to "warn" or "produce an error")

Comment: Holy god it works! Damn so complicated to write  Feel free to update my post and explain (this satisfies keyword is killer) :) Thanks

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance; it could be a few hours before I get to it

Answer (score 1):

If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the variable `TagConfigurations` with type `Partial<Record<Tag, TagDataConfig>>`, the compiler will lose track of any more specific information, including the relationship `Tag.UV_RANGE` and `DataType.TIME_RANGE`.  Instead, you can annotate types to parts of the data where you'd like such widening to happen, and then let the compiler infer the rest of it.  When you get to the part where you'd like to *check* that `TagConfigurations` is assignable to `Partial<Record<Tag, TagDataConfig>>`, you can use the new [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).  Like this:

```
const timeRangeDataConfig: TimeRangeDataConfig = {
    type: DataType.TIME_RANGE,
    toBuffer(interval: number) {
        return Buffer.from(interval);
    },
};

const commonDataConfig: CommonTagDataConfig = {
    type: DataType.NUMBER,
    max: 900,
    min: 200,
};

const TagConfigurations = {
    [Tag.UV_RANGE]: timeRangeDataConfig,
    [Tag.STANDARD]: commonDataConfig
} satisfies Partial<Record<Tag, TagDataConfig>>;
```

That compiles (so `TagConfigurations` does "satisfy" that type) but we can still recover more information from its type:

```
type TagConfigurations = typeof TagConfigurations;

type TagConfigurations = typeof TagConfigurations;
/* type TagConfigurations = {
    1: TimeRangeDataConfig;
    0: CommonTagDataConfig;
} */
```

And this lets us build a `TagForType<T>` utility type:

```
type TagForType<T extends TagConfigurations[keyof TagConfigurations]['type']> = {
    [K in keyof TagConfigurations]: T extends TagConfigurations[K]['type'] ? K : never
}[keyof TagConfigurations];
```

Here we [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over each key in `TagConfigurations`, [checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) for a property value where `T` is assignable to the property's `type` property.  This produces a type like `{[Tag.UV_RANGE]: Tag.UV_RANGE; [Tag.STANDARD]: never}`. Then we [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into this mapped type with `keyof TagConfigurations` to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the property types, like `Tag.UV_RANGE | never` which collapses to `Tag.UV_RANGE`.

Let's test that out:

```
type TFTTR = TagForType<DataType.TIME_RANGE>;
// type TFTTR = Tag.UV_RANGE

type TFTNUM = TagForType<DataType.NUMBER>;
// type TFTNUM = Tag.STANDARD
```

Looks like what we want to see.  So now we can define `Props`:

```
type Props = {
    tag: TagForType<DataType.TIME_RANGE>;
}
```

And then your component works as expected:

```
function MyNewComponent(props: Props) {
    const renderConfigurationForTag: TimeRangeDataConfig =
        TagConfigurations[props.tag];
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwEIFcBm2Q3gG8AoeM+ZAFykoEsx5sYB7AWwApYBzALnigB2ATwCUfLLnzEAvsWIgBmVvAAqULkVLkAyioCCAOQAiegEpH4AXngAGAB42bAGi1kAqgDUA+qcMBxAFErWwcARhdZeUVlIxooFSEABwQScngjUwB5AAUjTIB1A2CAcgycvMLilzSDNwBZdADTEtqGpqrXdIBNAz06gEkAYS9WxubrUp6+oZH6sY60lX66gJ9-IImllbWDQI7I2gFKfGwoMARBtlZmATUuWOpLgWxaDVTySiSQPgf4r4A6Mq5ApFAA+6TiCWS-1GTXg4N+UJAgKmA2GsNMAG5OqwoHY+NEAEb4bFpViHAlKYkwGTEQ7HGCnc6qWisECmQRcEC-J4vN6dT7JH6QgFbVa+XYBUkfZgSPAwdj0-AANygEEprGpYgwOHl2NkgoQdx5Nz5wUurGut3UJuer3hLLZHIEXNtfOxxDANyo8DoTs53LivNefBUrPZAbd9us7zIhuF1CR-zFO0C1RlcvwiqOKrVGq1mjSaTglEwMAEOskMH+TDY2YZqogImlZGkEU93soiCuNyjvHgFqtxqDpujhY+XwTf2hGPTZFx+PgAE5HHP4OSBHwAEyrmQer0CH13YNcMs0Wje4Kx+AAbTu-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-zUFwz76kAA)